# Unusual table order when using xtable in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I am trying to print a number of x tables in a markdown document with some text in between. However, the output pdf dose not have the tables in the order that I had specified. I have attached the sample code and output below

````
 ---
title: "Table Test"
author: "Nishant"
date: "December 15, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---




#XYZ Factor correlation

```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='asis',fig.pos='H'}

library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
R.Name = c('Europe','North.America','Pacific')

x= array(0, dim = c(3,3))
colnames(x) = R.Name
rownames(x) = R.Name
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))


```

\pagebreak    

#XYZ Neutralized Factor Correlation

We next present the results for neutralized factor returns. Specifically we present the correlations of the residuals of factor returns after regressing them against the global variants of each of the factor and the market. We exclude the global variant of the factor in question



```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='asis',fig.pos='H'}


x= array(0, dim = c(3,3))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))
print.xtable(xtable(x))



```
````

Answer (score 2):

This is a latex problem (check the output with `keep_tex: true`: the tables are in the correct order in the latex document). By default, `print.xtable()` outputs floating tables. They are not positionned exactly where the code is, but somewhere nearby. You can play with table positioning to correct this. For instance (just the relevant bit in your MWE):

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{float}
---

```{r}
options(xtable.comment = FALSE,
        xtable.table.placement="H")
```
````

Comment: I have been doing that for the past day. It seems like this needs to be dealt with on a more case to case basis i.e. specifying the location for each of the tables. Anything more general would be highly appreciated

Comment: If you set up `xtable.table.placement="H"` in `options()`, it will apply to all xtables. If you want to set it on a case by case basis, `print(xtable(x),table.placement="H")` should work

Comment: I tried all the possible placement options on a global basis. Nothing seems to put the tables in the right place. Is there a way to maybe turn off the floating environment and gain more granular control over the positioning

Comment: `options(xtable.floating=FALSE)` seems to turn it off altogether but the results are much more weird than with my proposed solution

Comment: Yes I agree. Seems like its going to be a dead end in terms of using xtable for so many tables.